# Android java.land.nullpointer exception or source not found at onClick(View v)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-logcat

I am trying to run a simple Android tutorial. I have written a few already, and have come to expect the *source not found* error to be a bit misleading, so I ignore it, but this is a stack trace and some code. It appears to be some null pointer, but I can't seem to work it out.

```
package com.rlee.randomquotes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RandomQuotes extends Activity {
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    EditText Quote;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Capture our button from layout
        Button setButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
        Button getButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.genRan);
        // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
        setButton.setOnClickListener(mAddListener);
        getButton.setOnClickListener(mAddListener);
    }

    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener.

    private OnClickListener mAddListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
```

}

and the error

```
08-03 21:08:18.325: ERROR/jdwp(2383): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.rlee.randomquotes/com.rlee.randomquotes.RandomQuotes}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at com.rlee.randomquotes.RandomQuotes.onCreate(RandomQuotes.java:23)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     ... 11 more
08-03 21:17:59.915: ERROR/power(852): Failed setting last user activity: g_error=0
```

Is this the correct stack trace from LogCat? And where is the error?

the main.xml, and string.xml below are where the buttons are initialized. Am I correct in saying this. Hopefully this html will show.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html --> <br/><pre><Button
android:id="@+id/go"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/press"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/genRan"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/genRan"
/></pre> <br/><pre>  <string name="press">Press Me!</string>
<string name="genRan">Generate Random Quote!</string>
```

Comment: i also had this random quotes tutorial but it was showing a toast of null pointer exception on button click in emulator if you want to learn database this is a better tutorial http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, I will do. But I will persist to find out why I get these erros, I like the aweser below, I will try that and update.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your get and set buttons are not null. Are you sure that those are the ids of your buttons? If those are the ids try to `Clean` your project, maybe even manually delete the `R.java` generated file, because sometimes it gets messed up.

Comment: Yep I've had the same problem before. Step through code and make sure neither button is Null before trying to setOnClicks.

Comment: I really think the clean must ahve worked, I didn't get to delete R.java, but for some reason its working now. would love to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the correct StackTrace from the Logcat.  The most useful information is found in these lines

```
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at com.rlee.randomquotes.RandomQuotes.onCreate(RandomQuotes.java:23)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-03 21:08:37.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2383):     ... 11 more
```

The Logcat is telling you that you have a NullPointerExcepotion on line 23 of your RandomQuotes class. This is line 23 from your code

```
setButton.setOnClickListener(mAddListener);
```

Since you are getting a NullPointerException, `setButton` must be null at this point, meaning it wasn't properly initialized by `Button setButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);`.

Check your main.xml file to make sure that you have declared a button with the attribute `android:id="@+id/go"`.

Comment: Sounds good, just edit your original question to include the XML. That will let you format everything properly.

Comment: Thanks, got it. next time I will take more time to read, rather than get so excited to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I notice u have a DBAdapter being initialized in your class. I faced similar null pointer exception issues a few days back when using database adapters.

Basically, the issue may be that the Database is either being closed somewhere in the Activity Lifecycle or isn't being opened properly - BEFORE your DBAdapter tries to access the database in this activity.

So my suggestion is - comment out any database close() calls in your application and check that the database is opened open & initialized before the DBAdapter tries to access it and try running again.

In my case, the issue was that in the Activity.OnStop() function in my calling activity, I had put in a call to close() the database. Now, OnStop() is called whenever an activity is hidden by a sub-activity, so when the DBAdapter in my sub-activity tried to access the database, it hit an error & raised null pointer exception

Here's the Activity Lifecycle -http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle

Comment: The strangest thing happened. 1st I had commented out the setButtonListeners, and I stopped getting all the errors, then I read your post, So I commented out the DBAdapter, it still worked, then I remembered I had commented out the Listeners, so I uncommented them, it still worked, So I uncommented the DBAdapter, and it still worked, no errors. pretty strange. but Ill keep a good eye on the database close calls. sounds very plausable that it could be the prodlem.

Comment: well this is quite rediculous, now, I uncommented the whole tutorial, and set it going, and it all works. I can only guess, a clean that I did updates the R.java class. but otherwise, nothing hs changed. anyone got any ideas?